# Как повернуть SVG иконку гамбургера вокруг оси X?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, svg

Я создал иконку из трех полосок, используя чистый код `SVG` в `HTML`.
Использую `CSS3-transforms`, для вращения верхней и нижней полосок для превращения в X-образную форму.

Проблема в том, что они вращаются вокруг своего центра, но мне нужно, чтобы они вращались вокруг центра иконки. Чтобы обойти это, я скорректировал их координаты `X / Y`.

Это вызывает массу проблем с Internet Explorer, Firefox и Safari. Хром, кажется, в порядке, но, очевидно, я хотел бы закодировать это «правильным» способом, чтобы он работал во всех браузерах.

[Здесь мой пример на CodePen](http://codepen.io/yahtzee_party/pen/ZGXXao):

```js
$('#burgericon').on('click', function(e) {

  if($(this).attr('class') != "open") {
      $(this).attr('class','open');
      $('.frstbar').attr('x','25').attr('y','-5');
      $('.thrdbar').attr('x','-35').attr('y','55');
    } 
  else {
    $(this).attr('class','default');
    $('.frstbar').attr('x','10').attr('y','10');
      $('.thrdbar').attr('x','10').attr('y','60');
    }
});
```

```css
.hamburger { display:block; text-align:center; }
svg { cursor:pointer; }

.frstbar, .scndbar, .thrdbar {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.35s linear;
    transition: all 0.35s linear;
}
#burgericon.open .frstbar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#burgericon.open .thrdbar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
#burgericon.open .scndbar { width: 0; opacity: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="burgericon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="90" height="80">
  <g class="icon">
    <rect class="frstbar" x="10" y="10" width="70" height="12" rx="7" ry="7" fill="#414141"/>
    <rect class="scndbar" x="10" y="35" width="70" height="12" rx="7" ry="7" fill="#414141"/>
    <rect class="thrdbar" x="10" y="60" width="70" height="12" rx="7" ry="7" fill="#414141"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Я также думаю, что изменение `X/Y` координат вызывает `blurry effect`. Я добавил снимок экрана ниже. Сначала вы увидите значок завершенного `X`, и далее вы увидите, как он выглядит, когда возвращается назад в исходное состояние.

Полоски выглядят не совсем прямыми,  по какой-то причине.

[Скриншот здесь](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93SRK.jpg)

Я  новичок в SVG-манипуляциях, поэтому не уверен, как правильно вращать элементы `<rect>` с помощью `CSS3 / JS`.
 Любая помощь или советы в правильном направлении будут более чем оценены.

Перевод вопроса: [Rotate a SVG hamburger icon into an X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30941833/rotate-a-svg-hamburger-icon-into-an-x/30942603#30942603)@[Thomas Lancy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5028773/thomas-lancy)

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30941833/rotate-a-svg-hamburger-icon-into-an-x/30942603#30942603

Comment: @Crantisz спасибо за помощь в устранении ошибки в коде. Может  у Вас появится желание разработать свой вариант ответа? Тема на мой взгляд интересная и я с удовольствием отдам решение любому, чей ответ будет на  технически хорошем уровне.

Comment: вот здесь более лаконичное и, как мне кажется, правильное решение с тем эффектом, который вам необходим: http://codepen.io/nelsonswork/pen/XbbJVx

Comment: @Игорь благодарю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш ответ в принципе неплох, но `transform-origin`, указанный в процентах, в Firefox не работает. Точнее работает, но не относительно элемента, а относительно SVG в целом (тестировал в версии 52). Поэтому, если вы хотите, чтобы пример работал и в  Firefox, и в Chrome одинаково, укажите `transform-origin` в пикселях:

```js
document.getElementById('burgericon').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    this.classList.toggle('open');
});
```

```css
.hamburger {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
svg {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.frstbar,.scndbar,.thrdbar {
  transition: all 0.35s linear;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform-origin: 10px 19px;
}
.thrdbar {
transform-origin: 10px 62px;
}
#burgericon.open .frstbar {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#burgericon.open .thrdbar {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
#burgericon.open .scndbar {
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="hamburger">
  <svg id="burgericon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="90" height="80">
    <g class="icon">
      <rect class="frstbar" x="10" y="10" width="70" height="12" rx="7" ry="7" fill="#414141" />
      <rect class="scndbar" x="10" y="35" width="70" height="12" rx="7" ry="7" fill="#414141" />
      <rect class="thrdbar" x="10" y="60" width="70" height="12" rx="7" ry="7" fill="#414141" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</nav>
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: ещё раз благодарю за ценные уточнения. Действительно FF криво воспроизводит код в моем ответе: одна полоска исчезает совсем, а две оставшиеся смещаются. Может ещё у вас будет вариант ответа с принципиально другим решением?

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете заменить JS-позиционирование с помощью свойства `CSS transform-origin`. Вы также можете установить его слева от первой и второй полоски с `transform-origin: 0 50%;`.

Они пересекут  друг друга, когда повернутся.

```js
document.getElementById('burgericon').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    this.classList.toggle('open');
});
```

```css
.hamburger {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
svg {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.frstbar,.scndbar,.thrdbar {
  transition: all 0.35s linear;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
}
#burgericon.open .frstbar {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#burgericon.open .thrdbar {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
#burgericon.open .scndbar {
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="hamburger">
  <svg id="burgericon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="90" height="80">
    <g class="icon">
      <rect class="frstbar" x="10" y="10" width="70" height="12" rx="7" ry="7" fill="#414141" />
      <rect class="scndbar" x="10" y="35" width="70" height="12" rx="7" ry="7" fill="#414141" />
      <rect class="thrdbar" x="10" y="60" width="70" height="12" rx="7" ry="7" fill="#414141" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</nav>
<div>
</div>
```

Перевод ответа: [Rotate a SVG hamburger icon into an X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30941833/rotate-a-svg-hamburger-icon-into-an-x/30942603#30942603)@[web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki)